# MySQL - Employees salary difference for last two months

Tags: mysql

I want fetch all employees salary difference for last two months.

Sample DATA: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02bfb/1

Expected Output:

[image]

Query I tried:

```
SELECT tab1.name, tab1.emp_id 
FROM a_test tab1 join a_test tab2
on tab1.id = tab2.id
group by tab1.emp_id
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why did you fail?

Comment: i used 'group by' and 'case' , i'm not able to write query to fetch as expected.

Comment: Can you show us your query? (please put it in the question and format it)

Comment: Fiddle's are great, but it's best to post the DDLs in the question

Comment: @KIKOSoftware : Check now i have updated question.

Comment: Plus, I can't relate the dataset to the desired result...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6a971/16

Comment: @Strawberry : The table is having details about employee namely. id is autoincrement, name is employee name, emp_id is employee id.

Comment: Rows in a database have no particular order. I cannot assume that the `id` will always correctly order the months. And the months are not easily orderable. I would suggest using numbers for months, and perhaps add a year, to improve your data.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware sure i'll update that.

Comment: To compute the difference you need data from two rows. One way of doing this is a subquery like Suresh Kamrushi showed you, the other way is a join of the datatable with itself. The latter method is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment a join seems to be the best solution for this:

```
SELECT a.emp_id,
       a.salary-b.salary AS diff, 
       CONCAT(a.salary,' - ',b.salary) as diff_str
FROM a_test AS a
JOIN a_test AS b 
ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id AND a.month_id-1 = b.month_id
WHERE a.month_id = (SELECT MAX(month_id) FROM a_test)
```

I've added the last line to return only the difference of the last two months. I could have done `WHERE a.month_id = MONTH(NOW())` but I chose to select the last month from the data table. Note that the subquery here is not inefficient, because it is only ran once.

The result is:

```
emp_id    diff    diff_str
1       -26000    27000 - 53000
2         9000    32000 - 23000
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02bfb/11/0

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: This returns the difference for *every* 2-month period, not just the last 2 months.

Comment: That is true. I'll add something to select the last month.

Comment: but in test data, he shows month column string field and that is month name

Answer (score 1):

by using join and as you  stated last two month that why i use `now()` and `month` function and if month column contain month number

```
select t1.emp_id,t1.name,(t1.salary-t2.salary) as sal_diff from
    (
    select * 
    from a_test
    where month=Month(now())
    ) as t1
    left join 
    (
    select * from a_test
    where month=month(now())-1
      ) as t2
      on t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id
```

but if you use month name then use `MONTHNAME` in your month column then query will be

```
select t1.emp_id,t1.name,(t1.salary-t2.salary) as sal_diff from
        (
        select * 
        from a_test
        where month=MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(now()), '%m'))
        ) as t1
        left join 
        (
        select * from a_test
        where month=MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(now())-1, '%m'))
          ) as t2
          on t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select (parent.salary - (select ch.salary from a_test as ch where ch.emp_id = parent.emp_id order by id desc limit 1,1)) as diff, emp_id, name, salary, month from a_test as parent where month = 'feb';
```

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52a019/2

You can add/update where condition in main and sub query to have month dynamically.
like below:

```
where month = MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE())
```